# Using 'this' inside AngularJS services

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Please check the code below. I've edited a ionic example of popup just to illustrate.

On showAlert1(), I reference 'this' as is and it doesn't work. On showAlert2(), I use a auxiliar variable '_this' that receives 'this' and it does works.

I've seen this kind of thing happening in other occasions, and I believe it's 'Controller as' syntax scope related, but why does this happens?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

   this.testAlert = function() {
     alert('Alerting!');
   };

   this.showAlert1 = function() {
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, this).then(function() {
       this.testAlert();
     });
   };

   this.showAlert2 = function() {
     var _this = this;
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, _this).then(function() {
       _this.testAlert();
     });
   };

});
```

Here's a Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPJVNN

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"this" in javascript is not the same as "this" in other languages.  You can think of it more as the context of a function call.

The default call context on a web application is window.  However, when calling a function that is a property of an object, the context becomes the object.

So, in your example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
   //"this" refers to the controller instance here (controllers are created by angular with the "new" operator)
   this.testAlert = function() {
     //inside of this function, "this" will still be the controller
     alert('Alerting!');
   };

   //"this" is the controller
   this.showAlert1 = function() {
   //"this" is still the controller
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, this).then(function() {
       //"this" is no longer the controller.  It's probably "window", but it's possible that ionic sets this to some other parameter when it invokes the function.
       //since it's not the controller, testAlert() is undefined!
       this.testAlert();
     });
   };

   //"this" is the controller
   this.showAlert2 = function() {
     //"this" is still the controller, and you have assigned _this to also be the controller
     var _this = this;
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, _this).then(function() {
       //"_this" is captured by the closure created by the function call, and it is still the controller, so testAlert() is defined. 
       _this.testAlert();
     });
   };

});
```

You'll often see this in code:

```
var self = this;
```

With "self" being used in place of this in order to avoid the confusion that you've encountered.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
   var self = this;
   self.testAlert = function() {
     alert('Alerting!');
   };

   self.showAlert1 = function() {
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, self).then(function() {
       self.testAlert();
     });
   };

   self.showAlert2 = function() {

     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, self).then(function() {
       self.testAlert();
     });
   };

});
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks! Is there a way to know the context of all the object, something like a context tree?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'this' refers to the current object it's in. So in your showAlert1() function, the 'this' refers to the $ionicPopup object.

So for example

```
var parent = {
    value: 'parent',
    alert: function(){
        alert(this.value);
    },
    child: {
        alert: function(){
            alert(this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

if you do a parent.alert(), it will alert parent.  But if you do a parent.child.alert() it will give you undefined because the 'this.value' for child doesnt exist, it doesnt refer to parent.value.  So what this means is that this refers to the current object.

Answer (score 0):

"this" in the .then() callback in showAlert1 is referring to the global object. Try this out:

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

   this.testAlert = function() {
     alert('Alerting!');
   };

   this.showAlert1 = function() {
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, this).then(function() {
       alert(this === window);
       this.testAlert();
     });
   };

   this.showAlert2 = function() {
     var _this = this;
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }, _this).then(function() {
       _this.testAlert();
     });
   };

});
```

"this" is only working for showAlert1 and showAlert2 because you're referring to them as a property of the controller itself right here:

```
<button class="button button-primary" ng-click="popup.testAlert()">
```

What is preferable is using $scope:

```
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      Popups
    </title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="padding" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
    <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="testAlert()">
      Test Alert
    </button>
    <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="showAlert1()">
      Alert1
    </button>
    <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="showAlert2()">
      Alert2
    </button>

    <script id="popup-template.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <input ng-model="data.wifi" type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then the JS:

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PopupCtrl',function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

   $scope.testAlert = function() {
     alert('Alerting!');
   };

   $scope.showAlert1 = function() {
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }).then(function() {
       $scope.testAlert();
     });
   };

   $scope.showAlert2 = function() {
     $ionicPopup.alert({
       title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
       template: 'It might taste good'
     }).then(function() {
       $scope.testAlert();
     });
   };
});
```